# How to Configure VM's with static IP on Hyper-v host windows server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows, hyper-v, vlan

I have Hyper-V role installed on Windows server 2008 R2 installed on a machine with 32GB RAM and IBM System X3400 M3 Server. I created the Guest VM using the VHD that is already installed with Windows server 2003 SP2 using the Hyper-V manager tool.

The problem:

I cannot  ping IP address of the host machine from VM, where host is connected to network where i can surf and do remote desktop very easily. Even the host machine cannot ping the VM.

From the VM i cannot surf , do not see any system in the network.

Cannot do Remote desktop with the VM guest hosted on Hyper-v.

==========================================================================

Structure of my Network(Pls Note all the systems in our network are allocated Static IP including the HOST and the Guest VM):-

1. HOST Machine

================================

```
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.44(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

2. GUEST Machine

=================================

```
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.45
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

Please help me with examples that includes creating VLAN with Static IPs.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your virtual switch may be misconfigured.  Check out [this article](http://www.virtuatopia.com/index.php/Understanding_and_Configuring_Hyper-V_Virtual_Networks) and verify your settings.  If your host can't ping the VM, then you have some kind of switching/routing problem.

Answer (score 1):

How is virtual networking configured on the Hyper-V server? Make sure you have a virtual network defined as "external" and connected to the server's network card, and make also sure you connect the VM's virtual network card to this virtual network.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816585(WS.10).aspx